# split the last string after delimiter without knowing the number of delimiters available in a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

I have a column in a data frame that contains multiple words separated by a dot in between but I can never now the number of words inside this cell so what I want is to get the last word after the last dot

Column X:
[www.xyz.hgk.lmo.de.eu.price](http://www.xyz.hgk.lmo.de.eu.price)
[www.amazon.us.stock](http://www.amazon.us.stock)
[www.hhhh.com.price](http://www.hhhh.com.price)
[www.ebay.eu.stock](http://www.ebay.eu.stock)
[www.mmm.price](http://www.mmm.price)

Desired column values:
price
stock
price
stock
price

My trial:

```
x2['Desired Column Values'] = x2['Column X'].str.split('.').str[2]
```

but this is not correct because I can't know the number of '.' in each cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `rsplit`, then extract the last element:

```
df['Column X'].str.rsplit('.', 1).str[-1]
```

Equivalently, you can apply the python function(s):

```
df['Column X'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit('.',1)[-1])
```

Alternatively, you can `extract` a [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/W386RN/1):

```
df['Column X'].str.extract('([^.]+)$', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
0    price
1    stock
2    price
3    stock
4    price
Name: Column X, dtype: object
```

Comment: is it possible to get the strings between the first and last delimiters using this method ?

Comment: Tha'td be `.string.extract('^[^.]+\.(.+)\.[^.]+$', expand=False)`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'www.xyz.hgk.lmo.de.eu.price'
x_list = x.split('.')
print(x_list[-1])
# x.split -> takes a parameter called sep, it returns a list of words that are separated by '.', then to access the last element of the list we use [-1]
```

alter and apply this approach to your requirement